# Getting error when accessing 'widget' in state class in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, statefulwidget

Currently working in a project where I am facing a weird error that is using 'widget' to get stateful class property showing error. Here is my StatefulWidget class where I am trying to use controller, title, labelText using widget but can't access, give me error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NameInputTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const NameInputTextField({
     Key? key,
     required this.title,
     required this.labelText,
     required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String labelText;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  State<NameInputTextField> createState() => _NameInputTextFieldState();
 }

class _NameInputTextFieldState extends State<NameInputTextField> {
  bool _isFocused = true;
  final bool _isEmpty = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FocusScope(
    child: Focus(
    onFocusChange: (focus) {
      setState(() {
        _isFocused = focus;
      });
    },
    child: TextField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText:
            _isFocused || !_isEmpty ? widget.title : widget.labelText,
        labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4!.copyWith(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
      ),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
      autofocus: true,
      onChanged: (String value) {},
    ),
  ),
  );
 }
}
```

How can get rid off from this error.

Comment: Don't post screenshot.

Comment: Post your code instead of screenshot.

Comment: where is the error..?

Comment: it looks code is ok but error is showing in accessing controller, title, labelText property using widget

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in flutter sdk, after replacing with new sdk everything works fine.